# How to change length of line and rotate it dynamically?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit

I am trying to draw a simple straight line. For this, I am filling an `UIImageView` with some color with given width as, say 2 pixel and some length. Now user is provided with two `UISliders` out of which one is used to stretch the line and another slider to rotate. I use `myImageView.frame` to change the height and `CGAffineTransform` to rotate. It works fine until I change the rotation angle using slider. But once I rotate the imageview, The slider to stretch doesn't work properly.

I have searched and found that frames won't work after rotating using `CGAffineTranfor`.

Alternately bounds should work but that didn't work too.

Seeking help. Any brief code will help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try ? Just Place the code Dude !!!

Comment: Why don't you use quartz draw method?

Answer (score 0):

Give transformed bounds every time you apply a transform. This should work:

```
CGRect transformedBounds = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(myView.bounds, myView.transform);
```